# How to call a method in LWC in a record detail page AFTER committing a DML operation of the record to database

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, order-of-execution

I have a wired method (getRecord via uiRecordApi) in an LWC in the Opportunity record page. It gets automatically called **AFTER** the record is updated. But the data I fetch from this function from apex is the Old value. For example,

1. The startdate field value in the Opportunity record is '01/01/2020'.
2. I changed the startdate field value to '12/12/2020' and saved.
3. The getRecord wired method in the LWC component gets called and fetch the Opportunity data and the start date is still '01/01/2020' instead of '12/12/2020'.

Is there a way I can fetch the Opportunity data after the DML changes are commited to the database via a wired method (Not sure if there is any way to do it imperatively and it can get called automatically)

## OptyLWC.html

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getOptydata from '@salesforce/apex/OptyController.getOptydata ';   

export default class OptyLWC(LightningElement) {

   //Wired the getRecord method to get Opportunity data whenever the Opportunity record is updated
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ 'Opportunity.Name' })
     record({ data, error }) {

        //Calling imperatively
        getOptydata ({ recordId: this.recordId })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('data=> '+ result.StartDate);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        });
          
    }

}
```

Comment: the apex call can be included in the success handler for record submission.

Comment: Why not just include the StartDate in the list of fields for the getRecord wire handler?

Comment: Its not just the start date. There are a lot of fields that I need to take. The list of fields would be too big

Comment: Can you please share how you update the data